# Cross domain ajax in firefox

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, firefox, tomcat, grails

well i've got this problem, i'm bulding an application with backbone and require, and i need to solve this case: When the app request for services, the application does not work. I'm working with grails and tomcat as the base for the application, and the request are done in a server outside of the application. People from every where I told to disable the security of firefox, that is an ajax cross domain problem, but making this, the problem still there. Also I download an add on for firefox for corss and nothing. On chrome i could work because i put web security disabled, but in firefox i could not do it. Help please

Answer (score 3):

For cross domain ajax calls your server side application need to allow the different origin. For Grails there's the [CORS plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/cors) that will help you in this configuration.

From the [documentation of the plugin](https://github.com/davidtinker/grails-cors):

The default configuration installs a servlet filter that adds the following headers to all OPTIONS requests:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <value of Origin header>
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, authorization, accept, content-type, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
```

There's no need to change browser security configurations.

Comment: There's also [Tomcat's CORS filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) if you don't feel like using Grails.

Comment: Thanks guys, but the problem still there, the people told me that it's very difficult cors in firefox. I saw that ff makes a call OPTIONS http://my.domain/rest/mehtod and it returns "code":500,"message":"No resource method found for GET, return 405 with Allow header"